# If.-Value in a for loop: adding selected

Tags: html, django, for-loop, if-statement

Want to add the attribute "selected" to this select-field in my Django-Project:

```html
<form id="formselect" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="position_select" id="position_select">
    <option value="0">all positions</option>
    {% for position in position_options %}
    <option value="{{ position.id }}"
    {% if form.position.value == position.id.0 %} selected{% endif %}>
    Position: {{ position.position_order }}
  </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The result with this if method is that now every option is marked as selected in the output of that HTML. Is there a better way to handle that if-statement in a for loop?

I'm submitting this form on every click with:

```html
$("#position_select").on("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("formselect").submit();
  });
```

Comment: If you say all are selected, so your condition form.position value == position.id.0 is always true. That means your if condition needs to be updated.

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean with "updated"?

Comment: I mean, why is your if statement true for each iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
{% for position in position_options %}
{% if form.position.value == position.id.0 %}
    <option value="{{ position.id }}" selected>
{% else %}
    <option value="{{ position.id }}" selected>
{% endif %}
```

Or:

```
<option value="{{ position.id }}" {{ form.position.value == position.id.0 ? "selected" : "" }}>
```